# SQL join statement on 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

i am creating a join between two tables Product_Tree and Product on the two columns Model_Number and Manufacturer to return the matching columns.

Here are the 2 tables:

**Table : Product_Tree**

```
Col1,Col2,Model_Number,Col3,Manufacturer,Col4
111111,Pepsi,aaa,111111,aaa,description
222222,Miranda,bbb,222222,bbb,'description
333333,Cola,bbb,333333,bbb,description
```

**Table : Product**

```
Model_Number,Manufacturer
a,a
b,b
c,c
d,d
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT Product_Tree.col0,Product_Tree.col1,Product_Tree.col2,Product_Tree.col3,Product_Tree.Model_Number,Product_Tree.Manufacturer 
FROM Product_Tree 
JOIN Product ON Product.model_number LIKE ''''%''''Product_Tree.MODEL_NUMBER''''%'''' 
AND Product.manufacturer LIKE ''''%''Product_Tree.MANUFACTURER''''%'''';
```

**I am getting this error:**

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as `mysql`?

Comment: How is this related to "UNIX"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a concatenation operator to concatenate your `%` wildcard to your column `product_tree.manufacturer`:

```
SELECT Product_Tree.col0,Product_Tree.col1,Product_Tree.col2,Product_Tree.col3,Product_Tree.Model_Number,Product_Tree.Manufacturer 
FROM Product_Tree 
JOIN Product ON Product.model_number LIKE '%' || Product_Tree.MODEL_NUMBER || '%' 
AND Product.manufacturer LIKE '%' || Product_Tree.MANUFACTURER || '%';
```

I'm guessing that this query is inside a script and is quoted using single quotes `'` which is why you have single quotes all over the place in here. If that's the case then your quoted SQL statement would be:

```
SELECT Product_Tree.col0,Product_Tree.col1,Product_Tree.col2,Product_Tree.col3,Product_Tree.Model_Number,Product_Tree.Manufacturer 
FROM Product_Tree 
JOIN Product ON Product.model_number LIKE ''%'' || Product_Tree.MODEL_NUMBER || ''%'' 
AND Product.manufacturer LIKE ''%'' || Product_Tree.MANUFACTURER || ''%'';
```